# Can 'at the moment' be so long as to read a novel?

Tags: present-continuous, time, progressive-aspect

> > I am reading ‘Middlemarch’ at the moment.
>
> Some situations are not strictly continuous but allow for gaps, and
> the concept of ‘in progress at Tr’ is perfectly consistent with Tr
> actually coinciding with such a gap, as in the example. . . . Thus in
> the example it is the situation with gaps included that is presented
> as ongoing, so that I needn’t be engaged in actual reading at Td.
>
> (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, p.163)

The grammar seems to say my reading is a progressive activity with gaps. But can ‘at the moment’ subsume that long time enough to read an 880-pages novel?

Comment: You can read a novel at any moment. That doesn't mean you'll read the whole novel from cover to cover. You're just reading at the moment. Maybe on page 163.

Comment: I have heard "this" in place of "the". Strange!

Comment: There are plenty of budding actors who've been saying they're [between jobs at the moment](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22between+jobs+at+the+moment%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for *years*. It wouldn't be "abnormal" for such a person to say this even on a day when they happened to be working as an ["extra"](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_crowd_scene_actor_called).

Comment: @FumbleFingers As we say in The Profession, "There are no small parts, only small actors".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The progressive construction signifies (among other things) what grammarians call an *imperfective* viewpoint on an action. That is, it does not look at an action from the 'outside', as something with a beginning, a middle and an end—that is *perfective* aspect.  Rather, the *imperfective* looks at the 'inside' of the action, at an excerpt from the middle. It never includes either the beginning or the end of an action.

Thus, when you use the progressive construction "I am reading", you are not talking about the entire action of reading, you're talking only about the piece of the action you're currently engaged with.

Technically, you can express this using the classic description of tense by saying that Reference Time—the time you're talking about, whether that is a single moment or an extended timespan—is contained **within** Event Time, the timespan occupied by the action you are talking about.

What CGEL is talking about is the 'shape' of the Event. *Reading* here is episodic, intermittent. But the initial and final episodes—starting to read *Middlemarch* and finishing *Middlemarch*—are never included when you use the progressive construction.

Perhaps this graphic will help:

[image]
(The **R**s are episodes of reading.)

Answer (score 6):

No, "at the moment" doesn't subsume the entire novel-reading experience, but that's not what the example sentence means.

> Give me a moment to read *Middlemarch*.

Here, *moment* does subsume the entire novel-reading experience, but it is also nonsensical, unless you're Star Trek's Data or some other speed-reading superhuman.

> I'm in the process of reading *Middlemarch* at the moment.
>   I'm reading *Middlemarch* at the moment.

These two sentences mean exactly the same thing. Unless you're emphasizing the process, though, you'd be much more likely to use the second version.

If you're wondering why "at the moment", as in why not just say "I'm reading *Middlemarch*." — this is a sort of idiom. It can imply that you're always reading *something*, but at this particular time it happens to be the novel *Middlemarch*. It also emphasizes that you're reading the novel *now*, not at some unspecified vague not-quite-future point in time.

Comment: I think that "I'm always reading *something*" implication arises indirectly from the fact that by specifying *at the [or **this**] moment*, you imply this particular activity isn't one that you were or will be doing at many if any other "moments" [in your entire life?]. But it doesn't necessarily imply you're often *reading* [different books], or even that you're often doing anything at all. *"I'm reading ['Everything the average man knows about women'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World's_shortest_book) at the moment, but usually I just sit around doing nothing."*

Comment: Interestingly enough, the first example works just fine with the addition of a simple preposition: _Give me a moment to read **from** Middlemarch._